# Convert CSS Selector to XPATH

Tags: c#, .net, css, xpath, css-selectors

I saw an article online on [how to map CSS selectors to XPATH queries](http://plasmasturm.org/log/444/), so I'm trying to figure out if there are any .NET libraries out there that can do the mapping/conversion. Please let me know if you have any references or any ideas on how to perform the mapping (if a library is not available).

Comment: you could try this: https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/css2xpath/wiki/Home

Comment: @MUG4N, that's worth an answer.

Comment: I wrote a Pascal library to convert CSS 3 selectors to XPath 2.  But it directly creates an AST of the XPath expression, never keeping the expression in serialized form, so I don't think it would help you here... (Within an XPath engine, so you can mix it like `/html/css("div.whatever a")/@href`. IMHO They should add this to the XPath standard, no need to convert anything anymore. )

Comment: As a reference, I think you will find [XPath, CSS, DOM and Selenium: The Rosetta Stone](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/) and its accompanying wallchart useful, providing a more comprehensive set of recipes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the Css2Xpath library found here:  https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/css2xpath/wiki/Home

I have never used it but maybe you can share your experience with us.

Here is a small sample of usage:

```
String css = "div#test .note span:first-child";
String xpath = css2xpath.Transform(css);
```

Comment: There were some bugs with string literals in there and first-childlast-child don't work in some cases such as this one: `[width="150"]:last-child`. Otherwise it works pretty good, thanks!

Comment: Hi everyone - I'm the author of css2xpath (well, the port anyways). I've just released a new project, css2xpath Reloaded, to replace this one: https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/css2xpath-reloaded. You shouldn't have issues with string literals, nor with the pseudo-classes. It's not fully tested yet, but you might want to check it out regardless.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante - not sure if this is correct place to ask, am after xpath to css in c#? are u aware of any ?

Comment: @Ram: Sorry, it's been years since I've looked at this stuff. I have no idea.